# what device will give a history of heart rate (not just current indicator) by the minute

Tags: sleep, heart-rate, heart-rate-monitor, heart

This is a research project on *myself* actually.  I'm already physically active, run half and full marathons, and am involved in dance and Ultimate Frisbee.  BP is good and so is HR.

But I'd like to get a device that I can wear to bed, and the reason is that there is a point in time where I can "feel" my HR begin to drop and everything relax, and I'd like to punch a stopwatch off (and then just go to sleep), and then come back and compare the time start with the heart rate history and see how they correlate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For home use I'm not aware of anything that tracks overnight, and clinically (it would be way overkill as it is a heart tracing monitor) there is a Holter monitor, which monitors your heart tracings and records them for later viewing and analysis. Holters also need a doc to prescribe, if you talk to a cardiologist about why, he may be intrigued enough to participate.